# Ajax begin form on failure data not populating

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Ajax helper on my page.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Activate", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "AccountActivateSuccess(data)", OnFailure = "AccountActivateFailure(data)" }, new { id = "searchForm" }))
```

And the following JS functions.

```
function AccountActivateSuccess(data) {
        console.log('account activate success');
        console.log(data);    
        //do stuff with information in data
    }

    function AccountActivateFailure(data) {
        console.log('account activate failure');
        console.log(data);
       //do stuff with information in data
    }
```

The controller responds like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activate(MyModel model)
{
    try
    {
        //something spectacular
         return Json(new {success = true});
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new {success = false, message = e});
    }
}
```

When no error is thrown, the 'data' variable is populated, i can even put a message property in and get a handle on it on the response.

When an exception is thrown however, i get the following console error:

> VM34:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

It doesn't even get to the console.log's.

What gives?

Comment: could your return Json line in the exception handler be throwing an exception?  maybe it's unable to serialize the entire exception.  try replacing e with e.Message

Comment: generally it's not a good security policy to return exception data in the response. This could potentially inadvertently give away usable information to hackers such as file paths, database information etc. Instead let the application fail and the exception happen, let the client display a generic error message to the user, and have the application log all exceptions to the Windows Event Log on the server (at a higher level e.g. using an exception filter).

Comment: However to fix the immediate issue, writing AccountActivateSuccess(data) in your form config makes no sense. You're supposed to be providing the name of a function to run. The _definition_ of that function will _accept_ a data parameter as an input. You don't have any data to pass. The AJAX code calls the function and passes in some data, it's not your job - you just tell it which function to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually that I needed to do `e.ToString();` from my controller. What was also confusing the matter was that I was expecting the `AccountActivateFailure` function to run, but even though there was an exception, it was within a Try Catch so it was dropping into the `AccountActivateSuccess` function, and I was not setting an error message in here.

This is an internal application so there is no issue with server information being displayed on the page. The user needs to know exactly what has gone wrong, that is kind of the point of this system.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "(data)" parameter for the callbacks on the form definition:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Activate", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "AccountActivateSuccess", OnFailure = "AccountActivateFailure" }, new { id = "searchForm" }))
```

And also,please verify that the scope of the callback javascript functions is global.